# Retrieve cookie in OnTicketReceived event after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My ASP.NET Core application is using OpenID Connect to log the user in. After the user has logged in, I want to retrieve a cookie that was set prior to login. Right now, I'm using the OnTicketReceived event of the OIDC middleware.
To access the HttpContext, I'm using a helper class which uses a IHttpContextAccessor object.
The problem is that the myCookie variable remains null.
How can I retrieve the cookie value after logging in?

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...            
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            ...
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            ...
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTicketReceived = e =>
                {
                    if (e.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                            string myCookie = HttpHelper.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.MY_COOKIE];
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    }


public static class HttpHelper
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        accessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public static HttpContext HttpContext => accessor.HttpContext;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The HttpContext is available on the parameter so the helper class is unnecessary.

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTicketReceived = async e =>
    {
        if (e.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string myCookie = e.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[Constants.MY_COOKIE];
        }
    }
};
```

You can also access other services through the parameter via `var service = e.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IWhateverService>();`

Comment: You are correct that the helper class is unnecessary here. But the result stays the same. myCookie remains null with your code as well. I checked that the cookie is actually written prior to login and that seems to be the case.

Comment: Did you check the request headers? It seems a bit odd that it'd be missing :/

Comment: As I understand it, sign-in occurs after the `OnTicketReceived` event runs ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.2.4/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L123)). The cookie is null because it doesn't hasn't been created yet.